# HTML CSS How to swap css attributes

Tags: html, css, attributes, css-tables

I am working on a project and I have multiple pages. 
I only have one CSS file. I have specified the tr:hover attribute in a table for one page, but on another page I also have a table where I do not want this to be applied. Is there any way? It changes the color upon hovering, but I want it to be applied only on the one specific page.

What comes on my mind is to make a second CSS file, but I would rather not do it as we were told to try to get everything into one.

Comment: Separate class can be created?

Comment: Don't use a seperate CSS file. Use a seperate class - in fact, recently I had the same problem so used body classes. Or you could even write something like Sass where you can nest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answer here is the wonderful world of body classes. You would apply a class to each page, for the home page you could use:

```
<body class="homePage">
```

for other pages, other classes. You then target these pages on a per page basis like this:

```
.homePage tr:hover {background: pink;}
.aboutPage tr:hover {background: red;}
```

Alternatively you can simply ID the table:

```
<table id="table1">
```

and then target just that table:

```
#table1 tr:hover {background: pink}
```

...but I recommend the body tags as a good way to work in general.

Comment: semi-column misssing

Comment: Where is it missing?

Comment: After each CSS statement.

Comment: Nope, Final, and therefore single, statements don't require a semi-colon.

Comment: The moment OP decides to add another statement and takes your syntax literally, it'll break.

Comment: Thank you this is the answer to my problem.

Comment: OK OK I give in haha ;)

Comment: Cheers AllDani.com

Answer (score 0):

> tr.classname:hover

can be used for hover effect where classname should be specify in css file and html.
tr:hover is global for all tr

A separate class is best solution for these type of problems

Comment: No, inheritance is the best solution for these problems. Hence why you use a table-id and `#tableid tr:hover` as a selector. If you then want specific behaviour for certain rows, a class for those rows might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

How the f... 
A class on body? **NO**
Why? Body can only occur once, use an ID.

A class on each `<tr>`? **NO**
You put an id on the containing element, the `<table>` and create something like `#tableid tr:hover` in the CSS.

Seriously, the accepted answers are not good, neither as code or as advice.

Comment: A class on the body tag because typically the body tag will end up with multiple classes, at least in every project I work on it does, and very handy too. The accepted answer does not advocate separate tr classes, it recommends a table ID as you suggest

Comment: Why in heavens would a body-tag need multiple classes? Please provide an example where this is useful or smart?

Comment: My own CMS for example does this:

    <body class="pageAbout template_AboutsUs1 userLoggedIn userNameBob categoryWine"> etc etc.

Wordpress for example itself generates multiple body classes out of the box:

    <body class="page page-id-2 page-parent page-template-default logged-in class-name">

...and even to those I use custom functions to add more classes for custom post type taxonomies, browser type (sometimes)... all sorts of things.

The basic premise is that a handful of body classes remove the need for other id's/classes throughout the page, leaving a cleaner environment.

Comment: See: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/adding-to-the-body-class-in-wordpress--cms-21077 and http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/wordpress-body-class-101-tips-and-tricks-for-theme-designers/ for more.

Comment: Really? Oh my God, that is the stupidest thing I've (almost) ever heard. Why in the world would you need any of those classes for what you're doing? And quoting WordPress isn't really that great, they have a long history of crappy code and non-semantic HTML. I understand what you're doing, but I don't understand either the need or why one would want to do anything like that. It reeks of bad design. Sorry to say so.

Comment: _Why in the world would you need any of those classes for what you're doing?_ - If you don't know mate, then it'd take a long time for me to start explaining it to you :) Over and out.

Comment: That is a cop-out, but fine. I'll keep doing things the right, simple way, and you keep doing things with classes. Not a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128522/discussion-between-mayersdesign-and-junkfoodjunkie).